# How does didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:outputStream: get called?

Tags: ios, networking, bonjour, connection, nsnetservice

My first question is how do I get the `didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:outputStream:` callback in `NSNetServiceDelegate` to get called?

Follow up question: can I still establish a connection between a client and server, although I never get a callback saying that a connection was accepted (via `didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:outputStream:`)?

I understand that calling `publishWithOptions`, while passing in the `NSNetServiceListenForConnections` option is supposed to result in the `NetServiceDelegate` callback (`didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:outputStream:`) to be called. However, that callback is not getting called.

Here are the steps I am taking, to publish:

1. Create `NSNetService` with

   self.netService = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@""
   type:_serviceType
   name:(_name == nil) ? @"" : _name
   port:0];
2. Schedule service in current runloop, in default mode
3. Set the delegate to my Server wrapper object
4. call `publishWithOptions:NSNetServiceListenForConnections`

Here are the steps I take, to browse services:

1. Create an `NSNetServiceBrowser`, and set its delegate to my client wrapper object
2. Call `searchForServicesOfType` for the same service type and domain as `NSNetService`
3. List services in a `UITableView` for the UI, to allow a user to select a service
4. When a user selects a service, set the service's delegate to my client object, and call `getInputStream:outputSteam:` on the service
5. After getInputStream:outputSteam: returns success, I would expect `didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:outputStream:` to get called. However this does not occur.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did u figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:outputStream:` must be called from the side accepting the connection.

Once the service is available, you call get the streams

`[service getInputStream:&istream outputStream:&ostream]`

Once this happens on the side receiving the request the delegate method

```
- (void)netService:(NSNetService *)sender didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:(NSInputStream *)inputStream outputStream:(NSOutputStream *)outputStream
```

will be called

Comment: Yes, I understand that `didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:outputStream:` must be called from the side accepting the connection. In my case, the server also acts as the client, and still that callback method, `didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:outputStream:` was never called.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it is not the act of calling `getInputStream:outputStream:` on the client that causes `didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:outputStream:` to be called on the server.

On the client, after calling `getInputStream:outputStream:`, your client then needs to call `[inputStream open]` and `[outputStream open]` before the `didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:outputStream:` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

It's all a part of lazy initialization.

Calling `getInputStream:outputStream:` will give you back two perfectly good NSStreams ready to use.  So, say, you want to write some data?  First, open the write stream...

BAM!  `netService:didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:outputStream:` is called.